# "Azure Queues" trigger for Logic App - no help or docs on settings

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I added an "Azure Queues" trigger and I get these three fields:

```
Connection Name
Storage Account Name
Shared Storage Key
```

But no explanation. Is there documentation for this trigger? I see that it is a "preview".

Answer (score 2):

"Connection Name" can be anything, it's for you to remember which connection it is.

"Storage Account Name" and "Shared Storage Key" can be found under the storage account's "Access keys" blade, you can use either key1 or key2.

We're working on a better UI for you to pick storage accounts under your subscription without you having to fish the information yourself. It should be available within a few weeks.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus.

You will find a complete tutorial to trigger a logic app from a SB connector.